# get header of domains by bash script

Tags: bash, curl, awk

I write 10 domains in test.csv and trying to get the header of these 10 domains. but it won't read contents 1 by 1.

and run this script

```
for j in test.csv
do

awk -F',' '{ print "$1" }' $j | curl -Is | cat >> b.txt

done
```

I have about 10 million domains, and trying to get header by script. Any way possible ?

Answer (score 1):

`curl` won't read URLs from stdin unless you tell it to do so. And you don't need a loop for this (assuming you have multiple files). What you're looking for is:

```
awk -F',' '{ print "url=" $1 }' file1 file2 file3 ... | curl -s -I -K- > out
```

Notice the `-K-`, it tells `curl` to read command line arguments from stdin.

Comment: awk -F',' '{ print "url=" $1 }' file1 file2 file3 ... | curl -s -I -K- > out

i use
`code`
for j in xxx yyy zzz 

do

awk '{ print "url=" $1 }' $j | curl -s -I -K- | cat >> final-$j

done
`code`
xxx yyy zzz has 100,000 domains, but almost 10 hours pass final file is empty...

Comment: @Cor I posted a command which works fine as it is. Why did you alter it?